# Laravel base url display non SSL url()

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I enable force SSL via .htaccess. it's working fine and redirects to https://www.myappurl.com. Inside my application, I use Ajax to retrieve the category list. after SSL enabled category list not loading. it's shown without SSL URL http://www.myappurl.com. I also change APP_URL to https://www.myappurl.com in .env File

my .htacccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

    # ensure www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

    # ensure https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Ajax Code

```
 $.ajax({

        url: '{{url('getsateslist')}}',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
```

Comment: No need to chnage the `env` or `.htaccess`, use `secure_url()` helper instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `secure_url()` helper function generates a fully qualified **HTTPS** URL to the given path, change  :

```
url: '{{ url('getsateslist') }}',
```

To

```
url: '{{ secure_url('getsateslist') }}',
```

See the official documentation of [`secure_url()`] [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-secure-url)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're using `X-Forwarded-Proto` to determine the protocol then I'm assuming your site is behind a proxy which terminates the SSL request and the proxy itself connects to your site using HTTP then you need to [enable the "trusted proxies" middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies)

You can find a [basic implementation on github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php) (and it does come with the Laravel boilerplate) but you can implement your own as well.

For example if you're using an AWS load balancer you can do:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
}
```

This uses the package [TrustedProxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) which is a Laravel dependency so more information can be found there.